# What is the operator norm of this operator?

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{X} = C^1([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ and $\|\,f\|_{\mathbb{X}} = \|\,f\|_{\infty} + \|\,f'\|_{\infty}$. Let $A: \mathbb{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $Af = f'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.
>   Find the operator norm of $A$

I am not too sure how to begin here. I have several definitions of the operator norm, the one I have been trying is that 
$$\|A\|_{op} = \inf\big\{c \geq 0: \|Av\| \leq c \|v\|\big\}$$

But I'm not even sure what the expression for $\|Av\|$ will be...

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Another way to look at the operator norm is to see what the operator does to a unit vector:
$$
\|A\|_{op}=\sup\{|Af|: \|f\|_{\Bbb X}=1\}
$$
Think about how large $|Af|$ could possibly be if we require that $\|f\|_{\Bbb X}=1$.

Some more pointers: $A$ takes in a function and spits out a real number. Which real number it spits out depends on the function, of course. For instance, $f(x)=x^2$ gives $Af=1$, and $g(x)=\sin(x)$ gives $Ag=\cos(0.5)$.

But if $f$ is a function such that $|Af|=1$, what can you say about $\|f\|_{\Bbb X}$? How small could it be? (This specific hint is more directed at the operator norm definition given in the question.)

Finally, since you were wondering, the expression for $|Av|$ is $|v'(0.5)|$.

Comment: Is the expression for $||Af||_{\mathbb{X}} = ||Af||_{\infty} + ||Af'||_{\infty} = ||f'(\frac{1}{2})||_{\infty} + ||f''(\frac{1}{2})||_{\infty}$? If so, I have no idea where to go from here, even with the restriction $||f||_{\mathbb{X}} = 1$, as we are taking infinity norms now...

Comment: No. $Af$ is a real number and the corresponding norm is the usual absolute value.

Comment: I am confused... Please can you add an answer?

Comment: @PhyaicsMathsLove I added another paragraph for you to think about.

Comment: It is apparent that $|Af|\leq\|f\|_{X}$, so $\|A\|\leq 1$. But I wonder if $\|A\|=1$. To do this, let $\epsilon>0$ be small, I fail to find some $f_{\epsilon}$ with $\|f\|_{\epsilon}\leq 1$ and such that $|Af_{\epsilon}|>1-\epsilon$.

Comment: @user284331 Think about a function $f$ that goes in straight lines from $(0,0)$ to $(\frac12-\frac\epsilon n,\epsilon)$ to $(\frac12+\frac\epsilon n,-\epsilon)$ to $(1,0)$. It will have $\|f\|_{\Bbb X}=\frac\epsilon n + n$ and $Af=-n$. (If you like, use $g=-f/n$ instead, with $Ag=1$.) Of course, it's not $C^2$, but the corners can be smoothed out so that the function is continuously differentiable with no change in norm.

Comment: (Or $h=f/(\frac\epsilon n +n)$, with $\|h\|_{\Bbb X}=1$.)

Comment: I’ve accepted your answer, but I am still a bit unsure. I am not sure how small it can be etc., so if you can provide more details, it’d be helpful